# Angular typeahead: How to separate label from model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using typeAheads from angular-ui in a UI-grid. 
There seem to be a implicit connection between the label in the uib-typeahead and the ng-model.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="country as country.id for country in countrys | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" class="form-control">
```

In this case the **country.id** dictates that the value shown in the input after a selection is **selected.id**. But that is not explicitly defined.

However, if **selected** does not have a field called id this causes the input to show [Object object].

Can I decouple the model from what is displayed and from the label?

Here is a small plunker. I want the typeahead to list id, but I want the input to display the value of the model.
http://plnkr.co/edit/EnOefFQVcTBoaHxiCc5I?p=preview

EDIT: I changed the plunked to better reflect my problem. If I set ng-model to **selected.value** I will get a good result in the beginning, but if I change the value I will get a nested JSON in the **selected.value**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uib-typeahead="country as country.value for country in countrys | filter:$viewValue"
```

You should use the typeahead like this to have a better understanding of your typeahdead.
However, if you still want to use this with the id, you can use input-formatter. This attribute of typehead defines how your selected object is displayed.

```
function(ojb) {
return obj.id ? obj.id : obj.value;
}
```

You will return the id if there is one, otherwise you return the value in the selected object.